# Get Month from Calendar Week (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

I have the following problem:

In Microsoft's SQL Server, I have a table where a year and a calendar week (starting with Monday) is stored.
Now, I want to write a function which returns the month in which this calendar week starts (i.e. if the Monday is the 31th of July, it should return "7").
I haven't found a built-in function to achieve this task and I have no idea to implement this easily. So I hope for your help and ideas!

Thanks in advance,
Melvin

Comment: Try this. Select MONTH(getdate())

Comment: You might want to try `MONTH`

Comment: Please show how the values are stored in your table.

Comment: See the answer from M.Ali, he provided the sort of solution I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query**

```
DECLARE @WEEK INT;
DECLARE @YEAR INT;
SET @week = 3
SET @year = 2014

SELECT DATEPART(MM,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(3),
                 DATEADD(WW,@WEEK - 1,
                 CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/'+CONVERT(char(4),@Year)))
                 ,100)+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) AS [MONTH]
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════╗
║ MONTH ║
╠═══════╣
║     1 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you, that's almost the solution. But instead of '01/01/'+CONVERT(char(4),@Year) I need the "real" first day of the year (ISO) but I think I can work this out for myself, so I set this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  I had to reread answer and pull from M.Ali to get the full answer.  You also have to know the correct year if the first week starts in the previous year.  You may need to do some editing if your first week of the year doesn't necessarily include 1 Jan.

```
DECLARE @Week int, @Year int, @Date datetime;

SET @Week = 1
SET @Year = 2014
SET @Date = CAST(@Year as varchar(4)) + '-01-01'
SELECT @Date = DATEADD(ww, @week-1, @Date)

SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(d, (DATEPART(dw,@date)-2)*-1, @date)), 
  CASE WHEN @Week = 1 AND MONTH(DATEADD(d, (DATEPART(dw,@date)-2)*-1, @date)) = 12 
    THEN @YEAR - 1 ELSE @YEAR END as CorrectYear
```

Comment: This might be the full solution, but I will perform some tests for the special cases tomorrow to see if it works properly. Thank you!!