# How to Convert given text into the required date format in SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have an old database with a [table with dateEntered(varchar datatype) column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOLl4.png)  which can take the dates in various formats like 
A> 'wk231216' which means (Week)23-(Date)12-(Year)2016
B> '231216' which means (Week)23-(Date)12-(Year)2016
C> 'wk132717' which means (week)13-(Date)27-(year)2017
 Now I need to modify the above dates into this format as 'YYYY-MM-DD'
A> should become 2016-06-12(wk23 of 2016 is in June(06))
B> should become 2016-06-12
C> should become 2017-03-27

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?
Thank You!!

Comment: No Idea!! Badaboom..

Comment: I do not understand the *week*... You seem to take character 3 & 4 as day and 5 & 6 as year, but how do you translate *week=23*? This is a very strange format! Is it just the month, where a weeks first day falls into? If yes, is your first day Monday or Sunday?

Comment: This is a horrible "date" format and IMO you need to do two things (in this order): 1) Fix the source application so that no additional data is entered in this format (instead using real dates) and **then** 2) Circle back and fix the previous data. Don't keep throwing more cryptic data into your database. One should not need a [secret decoder ring](http://fashionablygeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ring.jpeg) to make sense of what  should be a date.

Comment: is the "wk" prefix optional? do you know the week rule used? there are several, for example week 1 is the week with 1st january, or week 1 is the week with the first thursday of the year, some years have a week 53, and so on. once this is settled, you should be able to work out an expression. I think this is a legitimate question, but please come up with an attempt in t-sql

Comment: Write your own custom script using a week number to month converter and parse the rest of the "date" value as needed. ► `declare @Year char(4), @Week TINYINT, @month tinyint select @Year = '2016', @Week = 23 SET @month = month(dateadd(wk,@Week,@Year + '/01/01')) SELECT @month` ◄ Insert variables in places of `2016` from your custom parser etc... - Though your issue will be when a week starts in 1 month but ends in the next (assuming that could be a thing)

Comment: 2016-01-01 was a Friday.  If the week on Monday, is 2016-01-05 ( the first  Tuesday of the year) week 1 or week 2?

Comment: create a cursor that fetches the dates line by line and then put update query with new convered date.

Comment: @MerHardik a cursor is not something you need here. RBAR (row by agonizing row) processing is horribly inefficient and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Cursor is a database object used by applications to manipulate data in a set on a row-by-row. it would be clean approch if someone is having old data and want to manuplate it and store it again! @sean

Comment: @MerHardik I understand what a cursor is. And I strongly disagree that using a cursor for updates is appropriate. There is no need to update row by row, you simply create an update statement that covers the rules and you update the set.

Comment: This is a simple update statement but what we need to understand are the rules. Help us understand the problem. You have three sample values posted, and four in the image. But what we haven't seen is what those dates should be. And the logic used to determine those values. Once we have the details this is simple. Without them, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a UDF, it won't scale, don't use a cursor, it won't scale either.

As a starter for ten (either there is a mistake in your examples, or I don't follow the logic 100%) you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (naff_date VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'wk231216';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '231216';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'wk132717';
--Preformat
WITH x AS (SELECT CASE WHEN naff_date LIKE 'wk%' THEN SUBSTRING(naff_date, 3, 50) ELSE naff_date END AS naff_date FROM @table WHERE LEN(naff_date) IN (6, 8))
SELECT 
    '20' + RIGHT(naff_date, 2) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(CONVERT(INT, DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(naff_date, 1, 2)), '20170101')))), 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(naff_date, 3, 2) AS new_date
FROM 
    x
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(naff_date) = 1;
```

There's a lots of "iffs and buts" in there, and   I did my best to remove any dates that would cause an error.  I would suggest trying this, but obviously adjusting the query to use your real table, then write the results somewhere else for sanity checking, hoovering up errors, etc.

I get the following results:

```
new_date
2016-06-12
2016-06-12
2017-04-27
```

So the same for the first two examples, but a month out for the other (but I think my result is correct here?).

I guess if your week was "zero based" then this would work better, it's also not assuming that each year doesn't have a leap year (as my original answer did):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (naff_date VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'wk231216';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '231216';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'wk132717';
--Preformat
WITH x AS (SELECT CASE WHEN naff_date LIKE 'wk%' THEN SUBSTRING(naff_date, 3, 50) ELSE naff_date END AS naff_date FROM @table WHERE LEN(naff_date) IN (6, 8)),
--Get the year, week and day
y AS (
    SELECT
        '20' + RIGHT(naff_date, 2) AS [year],
        SUBSTRING(naff_date, 1, 2) AS [week],
        SUBSTRING(naff_date, 3, 2) AS [day]
    FROM 
        x
    WHERE
        ISNUMERIC(naff_date) = 1)
--Now we have enough information for the whole date
SELECT
    [year] + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(INT, [week]) - 1, CONVERT(DATE, [year] + '0101')))), 2) + '-' + [day] AS new_date
FROM
    y;
```

Comment: Week 13 in 2017 is the week that starts at the end of March and finishes the 4th of April hence, while `2017-03-27` is the desired date but `2017-04-27` is what most calculations will result in.

Comment: I will apply "iffs and buts"  and make it happen as expected. Thank You for your wonderful work  Richard Hansell !!Thank You Fran!

Answer (score 0):

Being new to SQL I'm sure there is a lot of better ways of doing this but you could create the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertFromWeekDateToMyDate(@input VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS DateTime
AS BEGIN
declare 
    @Year char(4), 
    @Week TINYINT, 
    @Day TINYINT, 
    @month TINYINT,
    @hasWk bit

set @hasWk = case when LEFT(@input, 2) = 'wk' then 1 else 0 end
set @Week = case when @hasWk = 1 then substring(@input, 3, 2) else substring(@input, 1, 2) end
set @Day = case when @hasWk = 1 then substring(@input, 5, 2) else substring(@input, 3, 2) end
set @Year = '20' + RIGHT(@input, 2)
set @month = DATEPART(MM,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(3),
                 DATEADD(WW,@WEEK - 1,
                 CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/'+ CONVERT(char(4),@Year))),100) + ' 1900' AS DATETIME))

RETURN DATEFROMPARTS (@Year, @month, @Day) 
END
```

The call it similar to

```
update YourTable set DateColumn = ConvertFromWeekDateToMyDate(DateColumn)
```

You can tweak the variable types, names, function names, etc.. as needed but it should get you started.

The above is using the Week-To-Month conversion code from this SO post ► [**Get Month from Calendar Week (SQL Server)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983354/448144)

---

Testing the above Function using the following inputs:

```
SELECT dbo.ConvertFromWeekDateToMyDate('wk231216') as 'wk231216',
dbo.ConvertFromWeekDateToMyDate('231216') as '231216',
dbo.ConvertFromWeekDateToMyDate('wk132717') as 'wk132717'
```

Gave me this result (which seems to match your expected result):

```
wk231216                231216                  wk132717
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2016-06-12 00:00:00.000 2016-06-12 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000
```