# Get weeks in a month using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This year, August contains week #'s 31, 32, 33 & 34.

How can I make a query that gets all returns from each week in the month(8)?

Example:

```
select sum(a) as MyTot
from MyTable
where week numbers are included in month
```

Clear as mud?

I can get the return for each week because there is a field with the week number in it. I need to sum all the weeks that are in any given month.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Month from Calendar Week (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983108/get-month-from-calendar-week-sql-server)

Comment: Table schema and desired output would help. Pointers here: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calendar table, containing all kinds of data about dates - weekday, week number, day of year, day of month, month name, month number etc'. Then you can join your current table with the calendar table, filtering by the relevant month.
In fact, this might be a very useful thing to have, as pointed out by Aaron Bertrand in his [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) article.

Another option is to compute the first and last date of the month, get the week number of these dates, and use that to select the data from your table:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, GetDate()), 0)
DECLARE @EndDate date = DATEADD(Day, -1, DATEADD(Month, 1, @StartDate))

SELECT SUM(a) as MyTot
FROM MyTable
WHERE weekNumber >= DATEPART(WEEK, @StartDate)
AND  weekNumber <= DATEPART(WEEK, @EndDate)
```

Please note, however, that the [`DATEPART(WEEK, @Date)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments) return value depends on the value set by `SET DATEFIRST`. You might also want to look at [`ISO_WEEK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#isoweek-datepart).